# geom_path is not drawing a line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making depth profiles with `ggplot`. Some of the lines are drawn between the variable points using geom_path but some are not, even when I try adding "group=1" (which was the only solution I've found for this problem). I'm doing multiple plots for different lakes and for each lake there is one or multiple variables not getting a line by using geom_path. For the code below only the `Chl.a` variable is not drawing a line, all the others do. What could this depend on?

I also tried `geom_line` instead but this only worked for some variables since the it draws the line following the x-axis, but I want the line to go vertically following the y-axis. Can I achieve this using geom_line since geom_path doesn't seem to work for all variables?

```
gs <- ggplot(goodspirit, aes(y=goodspirit$Depth.m)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Temp, colour= "Temp")) +
  geom_path(aes(x=Temp, color = "Temp"), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=zDOmg, color ="z(DO mg/L)")) +
  geom_path(aes(x=zDOmg, color ="z(DO mg/L)"), size=1.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Chl.a, color ="Chl.a"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_path(aes(x=Chl.a, color ="Chl.a"), na.rm = TRUE, size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=zN2O, color ="z(N2O.nM)"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=zN2O, color ="z(N2O.nM)"), na.rm = TRUE, size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sal.ppt, color ="Salinity.ppt"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Sal.ppt, color ="Salinity.ppt"), na.rm = TRUE, size=1.5)+
  geom_point(aes(x=zph, color ="z(pH)")) +
  geom_path(aes(x=zph, color ="z(pH)"), size=1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", limits=c(-3,5), expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.05,0))+
  ylab("Depth (m)") + xlab("x") + ggtitle("Good spirit lake") + labs(colour 
  = "Parameters") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme_light()

gs
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcGyP.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide what `goodspirit` looks like or its definition? Seems like if you pivot the data.frame you might be able to create this with a single `geom_point` and a single `geom_line`  Also, seems like depth should be on the x-axis as it appears to be the independent variable

Comment: Here is the excel and txt file that I used. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eW_ZVTSTcxGpVWlPDn_98P3JRpiXhNz1. Since I want to do a lake depth profile I need the Depth to be on the y axis even if it is the independent variable. I had to z or log transform some variables to fit in one plot. Could this have changed my data somehow to not make the geom_path function work?